# Class still pass the old array in PHP

Tags: java, php, android

I have an android program that passes 2 value to mySQL, that is Time in and Time out. I don`t know what happen but I have a scenario that the data passed is incomplete. For example i will create a record and the only need to put is time in after i type the time i will click save so the record is time in has a data and time out is null. After saving, my auto passer sends that data to mySQL. The next thing I will do is to edit that record to add Time Out so both of them has a data. auto passer will run after checking to my database my both of columns has a data. Now this is where the error begins, I have a button call refresh which will retrieve my data from mySQL,create a JSON of that then send it in my android after the process the returned data has no Time Out and when i check it the data in mySQL has no time out also even i add it. I dont know what happened

What I did in my Java is to create a JSONArray the convert it to string the pass it in my php file then my php file decodes it then loop it while saving to database.

This is how i create a json

```
JSONArray vis_array = new JSONArray();

Cursor unsync_vis = Sync.Unsync_Visit_All();
while (unsync_vis.moveToNext()) {
    JSONObject vis_data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        vis_data.put("t1", formatInsert_n(unsync_vis.getString(unsync_vis.getColumnIndex("t1"))));
        vis_data.put("t2", formatInsert_n(unsync_vis.getString(unsync_vis.getColumnIndex("t2"))));
        vis_array.put(vis_data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Auto Sync Error", e.getMessage());
    }                   
}



public String formatInsert_n(String data) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(data) || data.length() == 0) {
        data = "null";
    } else {
        data = data.replace("'", "''");
        data = data.replace("null", "");
        if (data.toString().matches("")) {
            data = "null";
        } else {
            data = "'" + data + "'";
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

after creating that json, i will convert it to string the pass it using `stringRequest` then in my php i will decode it use for loop the save it in mySQL

Here is the php code

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $insert_visit_new      = isset($_POST['insert_visit_new']) ? $_POST['insert_visit_new'] : "";


    if ($insert_visit_new != "") {
        $vis_array = json_decode($insert_visit_new, true);
        $vis_count = count($vis_array);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $vis_count; $i++) {
            $vis = $vis_array[$i];

            $t1            = $vis['t1'];
            $t2            = $vis['t2'];

            $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO table t1,t2 VALUES ('$t1','$t2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t1 = $t1,t2 = $t2"
            $stmt = $DB->prepare($ins_sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    echo "done";
?>
```

by the way the code above is inside an `AsyncTask` and the class is a `BroadcastReceiver`

is the cause is i dont unregister my `BroadcastReceiver`?

or my jsonArray name from this class and inside my refresh button are same?

my question is whats wrong? looks like it still passes the old data. any help is appreciated TYSM

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: @Strange for a minute sir I will add it

Comment: @Strange done adding the php code

Comment: @Strange please tell me if u want to see the select or the json creation in php and i will add it